# ordinal-isomorphisms

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following theorem was stated in the notes I'm reading as "immediate" on the grounds that the composition of an order-isomorphism is an order-isomorphism, and the identity function is the only order isomorphism from (O, ∈ ) to itself.  For some reason I can't see how the theorem follows.  Could someone explain this?  Thanks.

Theorem: Let (L, ≤ ) be a well-order and O an ordinal.  Then there is at most one order-isomorphism, f:(L, ≤ ) --> (O, ∈ ).

Comment: If $f, g$ are two isomorphisms,  prove that $g^{-1} \circ f$ is the identity on the ordinal.

Comment: OK, so the key point is that h of q only produces the identity if h is the inverse of q.  Correct?

Answer (score 2):

The key point is, as you write correctly in your comment, the following: If $f,g \colon L \to O$ are isomorphisms, then $g^{-1} \circ f = \mathrm{id}_O$ implies, just by composing with $g$, that 
$$ g = g \circ \mathrm{id}_O = g \circ g^{-1} \circ f = \mathrm{id}_O \circ f = f $$
To prove that $g^{-1} \circ f = \mathrm{id}_O$, note that $g^{-1} \circ f \colon O \to O$ is an isomorphism, hence the identity.